# How can I use a custom theme with react-dates?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dates, aphrodite, react-with-styles

I'm trying to style my [`react-dates`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) `DayPickerRangeController` in Typescript, using [react-with-styles](https://github.com/airbnb/react-with-styles) and [Aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite). I'm using this code, emulating the code from https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#interfaces:

```
const ThemedStyleSheet = require('react-with-styles/lib/ThemedStyleSheet').default
const aphroditeInterface = require('react-with-styles-interface-aphrodite').default
const DefaultTheme = require('react-dates/lib/theme/DefaultTheme').default

ThemedStyleSheet.registerInterface(aphroditeInterface)
ThemedStyleSheet.registerTheme(DefaultTheme)

// Importing react-dates after registering the theme, as per the docs.
import * as ReactDates from 'react-dates'
```

However, when I run this I get this runtime error in console:

```
Cannot read property 'createLTR' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createLTR' of undefined
    at Object.createLTR (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:133281:47)
    at createStyles (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:9710:59)
    at WithStyles.maybeCreateStyles (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:9805:22)
    at WithStyles.componentWillMount (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:9739:20)
    at callComponentWillMount (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:42214:16)
    at mountClassInstance (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:42310:7)
    at updateClassComponent (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:43679:9)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:44320:16)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:47152:16)
    at workLoop (http://localhost:6006/static/preview.bundle.js:47181:26)
```

I do not get this error when:

1. I use the `registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme` function from the class (this doesn't allow me to style the component, though). (This surprises me because [the code in `registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/0d2f78c17fe217e7064c324e4b7b28d08679bffe/src/utils/registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme.js) looks the same as what I have (to me at least))

   ```
   const aphroditeInterface = require('react-with-styles-interface-aphrodite').default

   const registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme = require('react-dates/lib/utils/registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme')
   .default

   registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme(aphroditeInterface)
   ```
2. I use `import 'react-dates/initialize';` (which eventually calls `registerInterfaceWithDefaultTheme`).

I still get this error when:

1. I swap the order of registering the theme and the interface
2. I add the `ThemedStyleSheet` code at the top of my `src/index` file, as opposed to in the same file as the one that uses `DayPickerRangeController` (This is the suggested fix in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558841/1176156)
3. I put the exact code from https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#interfaces in Javascript, then import that into my Typescript file that's using `DayPickerRangeController`.

I have confirmed in the debugger that all of my imports are getting valid code, and not e.g. `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens if you are using multiple AirBnB components (usual suspects include react-dates & rheostat) since they all suggest this (in my opinion) slightly hacky solution to styling in their docs.

I'm sure if you do a search for `ThemedStyleSheet` in your codebase you will find this is not the only place you are using it. Also watch out for various AirBnB component 'initialize' calls, which, if run after your code, will overwrite your theme and provider and cause further trouble. I said it was hacky...

You must lift all `ThemedStyleSheet` related logic from *across your whole codebase* to the very top where it should be called just once with a combined, relevant theme before anything else is loaded. (See this github issue: https://github.com/airbnb/rheostat/issues/179)

Comment: Thanks @Abulafia. I've long since given up on their date picker, but hopefully this helps future people